# How do I create a custom TypeAdapter using Gson for Retrofit 2?

Tags: android, generics, retrofit2, gson

I'm using Retrofit 2 + `GsonConverter` with a custom model (`ResultVO`).

I want auto detect and convert the generic type using Gson. I found a solution (`TypeToken`, `TypeAdapter`) but I don't know how to create a custom `TypeAdapter`.

Here is my code:

```java
public class ResultVO<T> {
    public Result result;

    public Result getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public class Result {
        public String code;
        public ArrayList<T> data;

        public String getCode() {
            return code;
        }

        public void setCode(String code) {
            this.code = code;
        }

        public ArrayList<T> getData() {
            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

Retrofit2 interface method:

```java
@POST("point/getMyPointHistory.json")
Call<ResultVO<MyCustomModelVO>> getMyPointHistory(
    @Query("type") String type,
    @Query("year") String year,
    @Query("month") String month
);
```

Comment: Make `Result` a static class and parameterize it as well (I'm not sure if inner classes can be easily managed). + Your `getMyPointHistory` method, I believe, must be annotated with `@GET`.